# Android PopupWindow showAsDropDown() not working properly

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am using PopupWindow with showAsDropDown(anchor). When the anchor is at the top of the screen it works fine, but when at the bottom of the screen nothing shows up. According to the documentation for PopupWindow.showAsDropDown() this should work:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown%28android.view.View%29

"Display the content view in a popup window anchored to the bottom-left corner of the anchor view. If there is not enough room on screen to show the popup in its entirety, this method tries to find a parent scroll view to scroll. If no parent scroll view can be scrolled, the bottom-left corner of the popup is pinned at the top left corner of the anchor view."

Presumably, the popup is always anchored to the bottom-left corner of the anchor view. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PopupWindow out of screen when size is unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696246/popupwindow-out-of-screen-when-size-is-unspecified)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this .. may be it helps

```
mWindow.showAtLocation(mRootView, Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT, 0, distanceFromTop);
```

Comment: what is "distanceFromTop"? from the top of the screen? How would you calculate this?

Comment: @GOLDEE what is distanceFromTop? is it the anchorView?

Comment: Its margin from the mRootView or you can say achorView

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I thought I'd post my solution.  It looks like you have to explicitly set the width and height of the popupWindow *before* calling showAsDropDown().

```
    menuLayout.measure( View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, 
                        View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED );
    int height = menuLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
    int width = menuLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
    popupMenu.setWidth( width );
    popupMenu.setHeight( height );

    popupMenu.showAsDropDown( clickedCell );
```

In this case menuLayout is the view displayed in the popupWindow.