# PopupWindow goes out screen's bottom boundary

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

This is a simplified code for what I use to show a popup window when making a long click on a GridView item.

When the item on the most right the popup window gets adjusted to be within the screen.

**But when the item near the bottom of the screen the popup window is cropped(part of it outside the screen).**

How to get this fixed?

```
PopupWindow mDropDownMenu= new PopupWindow(list, WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);

mDropDownMenu.showAsDropDown(aView);
```

aView is the GridView item.

The documentation says about showAsDropDown(View anchor)

```
 * Display the content view in a popup window anchored to the bottom-left
 * corner of the anchor view. If there is not enough room on screen to show
 * the popup in its entirety, this method tries to find a parent scroll
 * view to scroll. If no parent scroll view can be scrolled, the
 * bottom-left corner of the popup is pinned at the top left corner of the
 * anchor view.
 *
```

But it's always pinned to the bottom-left and don't go up-left.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: I have the same problem. There's an old post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115401/android-popupwindow-showasdropdown-not-working-properly, But no working solution is given.

Comment: I've also tried using PopupWindowCompat on both API 22 and 25. No difference. The problem is still there.

Comment: If you set the height and width explicitly it works:
PopupWindow(popupView, 100, 100).apply {
            setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            isTouchable = true
            isFocusable = true
            showAsDropDown(fragment_person_details__description)
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android PopupWindow showAsDropDown() not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115401/android-popupwindow-showasdropdown-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I **MUST** set the drop down menu height to avoid this problem

```
List<DropDownListItem> items;

dropDown.setHeight( toPixels( 30 * items.size() ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. You have to measure the view and set the measurement on the `PopupWindow`.

```
...
private fun showPopupWindow() {
        val popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.standard_popup_window, null)
        popupView.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        PopupWindow(popupView, popupView.measuredWidth, popupView.measuredHeight).apply {
            setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            isTouchable = true
            isFocusable = true
            overlapAnchor = true
            width = popupView.measuredWidth
            height = popupView.measuredHeight
            contentView = popupView
            showAsDropDown(fragment_person_details__description)
        }
...
```

Comment: Thank you Bohsen, but is this an Android code? almost all of the code is not defined, including R.layout.standard_popup_window.

Comment: Also setOverlapAnchor(boolean) requires API 23 and I'm targeting API 16+

Comment: This is Android kotlin code using android-kotlin extensions. Just drop setOverlapAnchor, should n't matter. Should work witout it.

Comment: R.layout.standard_popup_window is just the layout that I want to inflate into my popup window

Comment: @Jack There's a PopupWindowCompat class for that.