# Display view like a spinner's list without relativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, spinner

For some reasons, I have to create a kind of custom spinner. I meam, I want to display a Button/an ImageButton and onClick on it, I want to display a list. But this list must be floating like with a spinner.
The problem is I haven't and I can't add a RelativeLayout as a parent.
So how can I add a view floating on the top and looking like a spinner's list ?

I need you ! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and use [showAsDropDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int%29) method to show it at any location you want, in your case make use your  Button/ImageButton as anchor view.

you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698709/1051147)