# how to make custom popup window in listview item android

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow

as question said , i made popup window on longclick on item listview , I tried this code

```
    private void Show_Comment_Options(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View popupView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupdialog_comment_option, null);

    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popup.showAsDropDown(view);
    int[] location = new int[2];
    popupView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    popup.update();
}
```

but the popup window show perfectly with items that in top screen but with low item it hide some buttons from window like this picture
[image]

how make it like facebook made
 and how make anchor o arrow like facebook make on item
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify height for your popup. Seem like it's a known problem with it: [PopupWindow out of screen when size is unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696246/popupwindow-out-of-screen-when-size-is-unspecified)

Comment: Why are you posting your answer as a second answer. Just edit your first one answer.

Comment: Because they are different and comments will be irrelevant.

Comment: Yes but it is not right way to post answer twice. Just need to edit your first answer.

Comment: not means height , i mean that popup drawn on top or bottom as position of item listview